# asp.net linq query datatable

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, webforms

I have been following this tutorial to implement edit/update functionality via a modal popup form in asp.net:

http://msdnaspdotnettuto.blogspot.com/2015/01/aspnet-gridview-crud-using-twitter.html

This is my code:

```
public partial class GroupSummary1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        DataTable dt;
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                LoadGroupSummary();

            }
        }

        private void LoadGroupSummary()
        {
            try
            { 
            UserBLL userBLL = new UserBLL();
            dt = userBLL.GetGroupSummary(2, 2017);
            gvGroupSummary.DataSource = dt;
            gvGroupSummary.DataBind();
            }
            catch (SqlException ex)
            {
                System.Console.Error.Write(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        protected void gvGroupSummary_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
            if (e.CommandName.Equals("detail"))
            {
                string code = gvGroupSummary.DataKeys[index].Value.ToString();
                IEnumerable<DataRow> query = from i in dt.AsEnumerable()
                                             where i.Field<int>("GroupID").Equals(code)
                                             select i;
                DataTable detailTable = query.CopyToDataTable<DataRow>();
                DetailsView1.DataSource = detailTable;
                DetailsView1.DataBind();
                System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
                sb.Append(@"<script type='text/javascript'>");
                sb.Append("$('#detailModal').modal('show');");
                sb.Append(@"</script>");
                ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "DetailModalScript", sb.ToString(), false);
            }
        }
    }
```

When I select the "detail" button on the grid view, the following error occurs:

> System.ArgumentNullException   HResult=0x80004003   Message=Value
>   cannot be null. Parameter name: source   Source=   StackTrace:

At this line:

```
 IEnumerable<DataRow> query = from i in dt.AsEnumerable()
                                             where i.Field<int>("GroupID").Equals(code)
                                             select i;
```

The dt object is NULL and I suspect this is the source of the problem. However, I have declared it above just as in the tutorial.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: What's a `UserBll`? Please create a [Minimal, **Complete**, and Verifiable example](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve/) of your problem

Comment: That means `dt` is not populated properly. its `null`

Comment: That is my business logic object. The data to populate the gridview is being returned and displayed. The error occurs after I have clicked on "detail".

Comment: Hey,
I would recommend not to learn webforms - this technology is outdated. I would start with .net core MVC (or razor pages ).
 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/?view=aspnetcore-2.1

Comment: Storing `dt` as a property of the class seems wrong. How do you know `LoadGroupSummary` is going to get called before `gvGroupSummary_RowCommand`. If you following a "tutorial" stop. Because it seems rubbish.

Comment: Yeah webforms is pretty 2008.... I've just had a quick scan though that tutorial and my suspicions are correct, it is rubbish. Don't load data into a class in webforms like this. It's very inefficient and prone to race conditions.

Comment: So you are suggesting the datatable should be declared in the function LoadGroupSummary and then loaded?

Answer (score 1):

`LoadGroupSummary` is only firing on initial page load, not on postback. Clicking your detail button to call `gvGroupSummary_RowCommand()` will cause a postback.

Simply remove the `if (!IsPostBack)` from your page load.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LoadGroupSummary();
}
```

**EDIT:**

Might be worth mentioning that if whatever data `userBLL.GetGroupSummary()` returns is static, you should probably only load it once. For Example:

```
private void LoadGroupSummary()
{
    try
    { 
        if (Session["GroupSummary"] != null)
        {
            dt = (DataTable)Session["GroupSummary"];
        }
        else
        {
            UserBLL userBLL = new UserBLL();
            dt = userBLL.GetGroupSummary(2, 2017);
            Session["GroupSummary"] = dt;                    
        }
        gvGroupSummary.DataSource = dt;
        gvGroupSummary.DataBind();
    }
    catch (SqlException ex)
    {
          System.Console.Error.Write(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: This might fix the issue but could have other knock on consequences

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Clarifying all code in blocks like that is much clearer, hadn't thought of that.

Comment: Thanks. That would explain it. But the problem then is that the modal popup would not be "instantaneous". The LoadGroupSummary takes over 15 seconds to execute.

Comment: Is it data you're expecting to change each time? Or is it static? The best idea would be to get this data once on page load and then store it in session to avoid running the database query every time.

Comment: Optimise your database call then.

Comment: ^ Well yeah or that

Comment: Thanks Jacob. I considered storing the datatable in a Session object but understood that it is not particularly efficient if there are lots of users.

Comment: If the data is going to be the same for every user, and you rarely expect it to change, you can use Application[] instead of Session[]. However this will only be refreshed whenever your App pool is refreshed (a typical server configuration has this at once every 24 hours). Session seems like your best option unless you're able to seriously optimise your query.